# how to get current image url (Android)

Tags: android, url, android-volley, picasa, imageurl

i am creating wallpaper app using this tutorial: see this: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/

in which i am receiving images from **Google Picasa Album** using **Volley**, and showing images in to **GridView** and **FullScreen**.

now what i want is, i want to get the **URL** address of the **current image** that is showing in **FullScreen**.

**AppConst.java**

```
package info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.app;


public class AppConst {

    // Number of columns of Grid View
    // by default 2 but user can configure this in settings activity
    public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 2;

    // Gridview image padding
    public static final int GRID_PADDING = 4; // in dp

    // Gallery directory name to save wallpapers
    public static final String SDCARD_DIR_NAME = "Awesome Wallpapers";

    // Picasa/Google web album username
    public static final String PICASA_USER = "freewallpapersapp";

    // Public albums list url
    public static final String URL_PICASA_ALBUMS = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/_PICASA_USER_?kind=album&alt=json";

    // Picasa album photos url
    public static final String URL_ALBUM_PHOTOS = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/_PICASA_USER_/albumid/_ALBUM_ID_?alt=json";

    // Picasa recenlty added photos url
    public static final String URL_RECENTLY_ADDED = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/_PICASA_USER_?kind=photo&alt=json";

}
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {
    private String TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context _context;
    private PrefManager pref;

    // constructor
    public Utils(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = new PrefManager(_context);
    }

    /*
     * getting screen width
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
            // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }

    public void saveImageToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File myDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                pref.getGalleryName());

        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Wallpaper-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#",
                            "\"" + pref.getGalleryName() + "\""),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Wallpaper saved to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context);

            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**FullScreenViewActivity.java**

```
public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;

    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);

        // hide the action bar in fullscreen mode
        getActionBar().hide();

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */
    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Image full resolution json: "
                                        + response.toString());
                        try {
                            // Parsing the json response
                            JSONObject entry = response
                                    .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                            JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                            JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                                    .get(0);

                            String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                                    .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                            // image full resolution widht and height
                            final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                            final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                            Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                                    + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                                    + ", h: " + height);

                            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                                    .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                            // We download image into ImageView instead of
                            // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                            // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                            // methods

                            imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                                    new ImageListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(
                                                VolleyError arg0) {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(
                                                ImageContainer response,
                                                boolean arg1) {
                                            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                                // load bitmap into imageview
                                                fullImageView
                                                        .setImageBitmap(response
                                                                .getBitmap());
                                                adjustImageAspect(width, height);

                                                // hide loader and show set &
                                                // download buttons
                                                pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                llSetWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                llDownloadWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // unable to fetch wallpapers
                        // either google username is wrong or
                        // devices doesn't have internet connection
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        // button Download Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
            utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);
            break;
        // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
            utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

**AppController.java**

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

    private static AppController mInstance;
    private PrefManager pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        pref = new PrefManager(this);
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public PrefManager getPrefManger() {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new PrefManager(this);
        }

        return pref;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            getLruBitmapCache();
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
        }

        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
        if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
            mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
        return this.mLruBitmapCache;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

please see this tutorial so you can understand proper:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-2/

Comment: Where is your Volley image loading code?

Comment: did you check tutorial link, i think it's "`AppController.java`" i updated my question check and also visit tutorial link then you will get all codes there, i can't put all code here.

Comment: please help see my answer i have new issue now, i need little help now

Comment: did you find the answer? see you are using `fullImageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());` to set the image on fullImageView `public void onResponse(JSONObject response)` see if you can get the url in that method and if yes then set the url to a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

u can create a text view in fullScrean layout nad show the url on text view somthing like this

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.your TexView in layout);
tv,setText(url); String url exsite on fetchFullResolutionImage() ;
```